# How to automatically parse damaged JSON documents?

Tags: python, json

I have over 3,000 JSON documents stored in truncated text files. Those documents cannot be recovered from the original source, the data is gone. I tried `json`, `simplejson`, and `demjson` to turn them into Python objects, but they all predictably failed. I'd like to recover some of the data anyway. Where should I start looking for tools to automate that process?

Comment: Can you process some of them?

Comment: What *damaged* means? How it looks? Could you post some example?

Comment: at best any such tool could just GUESS at what's missing. but the best it could do with `{"foo":"ba` is finish it off as `{"foo":ba"}`, and you'd never know it was `{"foo":"bar","baz":"qux"}`. so yeah,,, GIGO applies. you've got garbage for inputs. the best you can hope for is having garbage as output.

Comment: well... how can i recover something from `[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[`. please offer some examples at least.

Comment: I cannot post the actual files, but they are JSON responses from Instagram. If you have a look at output from the `/media/search` API endpoint [see: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/] and chop about 1000 characters off the beginning and about the same off the end of the response, you will get the idea of what I'm dealing with.

Comment: That seems really bad. Just to cover all options: trying to recover the original file (from filesystem) is out of play? It's not reliable, but you may manage to recover at least some of it.

Comment: Do all the JSONs have the same ordering of elements? I'd try to find a way to detect which parts of the JSON are missing (which would be relatively easy with the same order of elements everywhere). Then you'd be able to fill some of the missing characters correctly and recover some informations...

Comment: No, recovery from the filesystem is out of question. The damage was caused by the (still broken) `boto` library [see https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2207]. Whoever was pulling data from Instagram did not properly handle uploads using  `set_contents_from_filename()` and as the result of that S3 buckets contain chopped up files. My job is to recover whatever can be recovered. I know the data schema, as it is well documented, I am looking for clues/suggestions on how to attack this problem. It is an interesting challenge.

Comment: OK, I posted *try-to-be-an-answer*. It was more like a comment, but it didn't fit in here :)